# Rotate plane normal

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d

I have a 3d plane defined by a normal and distance, is there a way to rotate the plane to face a given point in the 3d world? I can calculate the normal easily (targetPos-objectPos normalized), however I am not sure how the distance should be recalculated so the plane keeps the same "origin".

I am trying to build the plane to intersect an object in the 3d world and face the camera so I can perform ray casting on it.

Comment: What do you consider the plane's origin?

Comment: Right now I build a X and Z plane that intersect an object in the scene, however for the Y I need the plane to always face the camera and intersect the object as well. For example this is for the X plane: PLANE_X = new CC3Plane(new CC3Vector(0, 0, 1), selectedObject.z)

Comment: So you need the distance of the object along a given normal? That's `dot(normal, objectPos)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your post correctly the distance is how far the plane is away from the origin along the normal vector. This means that if you're trying to rotate the plane but keep the same origin then it's impossible since changing the normal will move the whole plane around the origin.

It might be best to define a plane as two vectors, a position vector(p) and a normal vector(n), this gives the vector equation of a plane:
p.n=d where d is a scalar value.

This would allow you to change the direction of the plane easily, for example if you wanted the plane to point at a point, P1, then you can calculate the new normal, n2, by:
n2 = normalised(P1 - p).

Comment: This is a possible solution but the planes are used in their current form in frustum culling and other places, so changing the representation without a way to preserve the compatibility is not the best option :(

Comment: Are you using the camera's position as the origin?

Comment: The camera is in a random position, the object also, the plane is defined by a normal and distance to the origin of the world.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible then without either using two vectors to define a plane or by having the camera at the origin. I recently wrote a raytracer in C++ and I found using two vectors to define a plane far easier in the long run as originally I had defined it as you have.